# Using common js with es templates?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have always used cdn to link to my local script files to load javascript files for my ejs templates. I was looking at `charts.js` today and the installation documentation says that I can either load the lib via cdn or through commonjs. I wanted to try commonjs this time

I installed the lib doing `npm install common.js` . The documentation says:

```
var Chart = require('chart.js');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {...});
```

Now, I know I can do this in my js file. Should I be making a charts.js file with just one line :

```
var Chart = require('chart.js');
```

and then import it using `<script src ="chart.js">` in my ejs file?

Comment: No, you have to bundle it using (e.g.) webpack

Comment: Is doing it this way faster than using CDN?

Comment: It depends. But the code youve shown just doesnt work, there is no `require` on the browser.